# Comparar duas listas elemento por elemento:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Oi estou tentando desenvolver um código, o código é:

```
lista1 = ['5','5','1','4']
lista2 = ['5','5','0','1']
```

Eu estava tentando fazer ele comparar cada elemento das lista2 com a lista 1 e ele identificar depois elemento por elemento. Na lista 2 se o elemento for igual e no indice correto da lista 1, se o elemento for igual e no indice errado, se o elemento for errado. O output seria mais ou menos:

```
>>indice 0: elemento da lista 2 é igual ao da lista 1
>>indice 1: elemento da lista 2 é igual ao da lista 1
>>indice 2: elemento da lista 2 não é igual ao da lista 1
>>indice 3: elemento da lista 2 é igual ao da lista 1 mas está no indice errado
```

Eu tentei usa for, e dentro um if usando if lista2[2] in lista1, mas não consegui resolver do jeito que eu queria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você faria manualmente? Ou seja, você compararia a lista item a item. Se o item de mesmo índice da primeira lista for igual ao ao da segunda você notifica que são iguais, senão você verifica se ele existe na outra lista ou, em caso contrário, o valor não existe na outra lista.

Uma solução simples de implementar seria usando a função `zip()` para combinar os elementos da lista, assim...

```py
lista_1 = ['5','5','1','4']
lista_2 = ['5','5','0','1']

for index,data in enumerate(zip(lista_1,lista_2)):
    i, j = data
    print(f"Índice {index}: ", end="")
    if i == j:
        print("Valores são iguais.")
    elif j in lista_1:
        print("Valores iguais mas em índice diferente.")
    else:
        print("Valores diferentes.")
```

E o resultado:

```
Índice 0: Valores são iguais.
Índice 1: Valores são iguais.
Índice 2: Valores diferentes.
Índice 3: Valores iguais mas em índice diferente.
```

O uso da função `enumerate()` é para gerar o número sequencial para os índices.